# How to return string 'add to friend' in php?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to display the appropriate string:

- If the user is a friend then the function should return friend.
- If the user is waiting for the response to the sent invitation, it should return waiting,
- in other cases, the function should return "add to a friend".

The problem is that the first two strings return correctly, but if someone is not among friends, it does not return "add to a friend". Maybe someone knows where the problem is, because I'm trying to find it, but I can't.

```
public function status()
{
    $field = $_GET['id'];
    $field2 = $_SESSION['id'];
    $sql = $this->database->connect()->prepare("SELECT status FROM user JOIN friend ON user.id = friend.request_from_id where  request_to_id = :session and request_from_id = :get OR  request_to_id = :get and request_from_id = :session");
    $sql->bindParam(':session', $field, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $sql->bindParam(':get', $field2, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $sql->execute();

    if ($sql->rowCount())
    {
       $row = $sql->fetch();


        if($row['status']== 'friend')
        {
            return 'friend';
        }else if($row['status']=='waiting')
        {
            return  'Waiting';

        }else
            return 'Add to a friend';
    }
}
```

Comment: Help us help you - share some sample data and the result you're trying to get for it

Comment: I wrote that if the user is not friend and does not expect response to the invitation, it should return add to friend, but not. The table in the database has 4 columns, id, request_from_id, request_to_id and status. Now do you understand what I mean?

Answer (score 0):

Add an else condition to the outer if

```
if ($sql->rowCount())
{
   $row = $sql->fetch();
    if($row['status']== 'friend')
     {
          return 'friend';
      }else if($row['status']=='waiting')
      {
           return  'Waiting';
       }else
                return 'Add to a friend';
   }else
            return 'Add to a friend';
```